# Does a lack of status code mean the request failed?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, httpresponse

What does it mean when the Edge DevTools Network tab shows the URL in red and no status code?

For example:

[image]

The browser shows "Hmm... can't reach this page" - does this mean the request simply didn't find an address in DNS resolution?

Comment: HTTP responses **always** have status code, by the standard definition. Lack of it means the browser didn't get the response in time. It could mean an aborted request, or that it timed-out or that the server didn't respond or can't be connected with.

Comment: How can I determine the difference in my case?

Answer (score 1):

I tested the URL in [Postman](https://www.postman.com/downloads/) and it showed

```
Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 123.45.678.90:80
```

So I have answered my question and commented question: Try the URL in a command line or developer client.